# Can we find out div's height after it's rendered in .resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a structure like this,

```
<div id="A">
 <div id="A1">
    <div id="B1"></div>
    <div id="B2"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="A2"></div>
</div>
```

`A2` and `B2` have table's in them, `B1` is just 4 checkboxes.

I want `A1` and `A2` to be 50/50  % on the page, it works perfectly at the moment. But when someone resizes there browser window, my A1 gets much more height and sometimes much less height.

**JS**
// I will add it in a hour or so

### Question

Can I find out height of `B1` in method `.resize` when someone resizes there browser and this has to be happen before rendering as well as then I will size `B2` based on `B1` height.

Comment: The answer is: yes, you can do that. However, shouldn't something like `#B1 { height: 50%; }` in CSS also work? No need for JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/dfanhzzr/

Comment: you can use bootstrap to fix this issue also u can use precentage in CSS

Comment: @FelixKling - I modified the fiddle according to my div, i tried as best as i could - http://jsfiddle.net/dfanhzzr/1/ , problem is I cannt set height on checkboxes div, as when windows resizes it's height varies from 39 - 98 and so, and instead of B1 and B2 sharing there given height, they use more

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of particular element in javascript by using `offsetHeight` property,

In your case, to get the height of `B1`, do something like

```
var B1Height = document.getElementById('B1').offsetHeight;
```

**What offsetHeight is?**

offsetHeight = height + padding + scrollBar + border.

offsetHeight does not include the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var B1Height = $("#B1")[0].clientHeight;
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gqv6te6n/)